# Map with a queue

Tags: java, dictionary, queue

So I need to manage a bunch of log files for unique IDs.
For my map I want the unique ID to be the key. However, the log file I need to manage
may contain several entries for each ID.

So my question is how would I go about doing something like this:

Map (unique ID, (Queue of events))

So each time I come across a new event in the log for the unique ID how would I add that
event to the queue of the appropriate key.

EDIT:
For example:

```
Event e = new Event();
map.put(e.ID, queue.add(e));
```

Something like that?

Comment: `Map<String, Queue<Event>>`?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want! haha
How would I go about adding events to the queue?

Comment: You can just get the queue from the map and add the event to it

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet will give you an idea on how to do it. Note that this code is not taking concurrency into consideration so if your code is multi-threaded, you may have to add some synchronization logic around accessing map. Also underlying Queue data structure used will depend on how you intend to use this queue.

```
Queue<Event> queue;
if(map.contains(e.ID)){
  queue = map.get(e.ID);
} else{
  queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Event>();
  map.put(queue);
}
queue.add(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this:

```
Event e = new Event();

// get queue from map
Queue<Event> eventQueue = map.get(e.ID);

if(eventQueue == null){
    // no queue existed in map with e.ID
    // create new queue, add to map
    eventQueue = new LinkedList<Event>();
    map.put(e.ID, eventQueue); 
}

// add event in queue
eventQueue.add(e);
```

Your queue can be specific queue implementation like `LinkedList` or `ArrayBlockingQueue`, so

```
eventQueue = new LinkedList<Event>();
```

or

```
eventQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Event>();
```

Answer (score 0):

declaring the queue of `Event` object.

```
Queue<Event> queue=new LinkedList<>();
..........
..........
```

`Map` declaration to have `key` as the `id` (`String` type) and queue as value:

```
Map<String, Queue<Event>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Now here comes how to add events to the map:

```
if(map.contains(id)){
  queue = map.get(e.ID);
  queue.offer(event);
}
else{
    queue=new LinkedList<>();
    map.put(id, queue);
    queue.offer(event);
}
```